# Upload object to a sub-directory in GCS bucket with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-storage

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "picture" {
  name   = "butterfly01"
  source = "/images/nature/garden-tiger-moth.jpg"
  bucket = "image-store"
}
```

What I found in Terraform documentation is uploading an object to a bucket. But i dont see any documentation if we want to upload an object to a sub-directory in the Bucket. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Cloud Storage the directories don't exist: the forward slashes you see are part of the object name, not directories of folders.
In fact you cannot create empty folders in a gcs bucket.

If you want to write the file to `gs://image-store/some/arbitrary/path/butterfly01`, just add the forward slashes to the name of the object like this:

```
# Writes to gs://image-store/some/arbitrary/path/butterfly01

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "picture" {
  name   = "some/arbitrary/path/butterfly01"
  source = "/images/nature/garden-tiger-moth.jpg"
  bucket = "image-store"
}
```

In GCS it is usually better to have a bucket for each purpose than a folder unless you need to have data partitioned in a folder to be used by Spark, Presto, etc.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot, I will try it out!!
The folder is auto-created, when creating a composer environment GCP auto-creates a folder for DAGs

Comment: For composer (airflow) people use either CI/CD to populate their DAGs or nothing at all. If you don't plan to use CI/CD yet, enable object versioning in the Bucket just to be sure you don't get mad troubleshooting stuff that used to work 2 days ago. If you have CI/CD, *disable* object versioning since you already have history in your repo.

Comment: Can you guide me to some documentation which explains how to upload DAGs to GCS using CI/CD?

Comment: Pro tips: folders don't exist in Cloud Storage

Comment: Thanks @IñigoGonzález , I was able to reach the desired result following your explanation!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the tip, I have learned something new today